# React on rails showing blank webpage, reporting an error that was already corrected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using ruby and react to build a todoManager for basic CRUD operations. It was running ok previously But my webpage suddenly started showing blank pages. And when inspecting source it shows an error in jsx file that I have already corrected.
I have tried rails server for more than twenty times but it stays the same. The server never reported any error.

```
SyntaxError: /home/gycc/todoManager/app/javascript/components/NewTask.jsx: Unexpected token (59:47)

  57 |              throw new Error("Network response was not ok creating gycc");
  58 |          })
> 59 |          .then(response => this.props.history.push(({`/task/${task.id}`}))
     |                                                      ^
  60 |          .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
  61 |  }
  62 |
```

**this line is already changed to**

**.then(response => this.props.history.push("/task"))**

**but the webpage still shows the error before I made the correction.**

My package.json is below

```
{                                                                                                                         "name": "todoManager",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
"@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
"@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
"@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
"@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.0",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
},
"version": "0.1.0",
"devDependencies": {
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.8",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
}
}
```

I have tried reinstalling npm and bundle update etc... But the problem is not solved.
Thank you very much for your kind help!
[The source code](https://github.com/gycc7253/cvwoFirstAssignment.git)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to remove `({})` part from your `push()` function call.

What about if in `.then` callback you change it to:

```
this.props.history.push(`/task/${task.id}`)
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: yup I have already edited that part. But the webpage apparently does not know I have made the edition and still showing the previous version of my jsx file.

Comment: If you have the repo and the changes pushed into GIT then try to delete the whole folder, clone it again then reinstalling with `npm install`. Sometimes that solves these types of issues. Let me know how it goes, thanks.

Comment: @yichaoGuo Just locally, IF you saved everything what you changed into your GIT repository. Please do NOT delete the remote GIT repository on GitHub. You can think about like starting from scratch on your machine, first step is cloning the GIT repo then do `npm install` locally.

Comment: yup i tried to do as you said. But there is another error showing up says Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError. I looked through many posts but did not solve the problems. Eventually I decided to redo it. Thank you for your suggestions tho!